# Facing Responsive Issue With Slider On My Website

Tags: magento, slider, responsive

Can anyone help me fix the responsive code issue with my website slider!

Url - https://www.aviratefashion.in/

[Image Is Getting Cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whWb0.png)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your website you need to follow some steps listed below to resolve the issue:-
You need to remove the min-height attribute from settings_default.css at line 32.
CSS path is:-[CSS link here](https://www.aviratefashion.in/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/css/configed/settings_default.css)

If you need to add this attribute for larger screens then so use media queries for better results.